# How to order dynamic structures in java

Tags: java, list, stack

I was studying for a Java test, and i found an exercise in which I have a stack of number    (i.e, 2-4-1-5-3, being 2 the first one that was inserted, and 3 the one you can peek on), and a circular list of characters (i.e, a->d->c->b->e->, being a the first node) so if the first number of the stack is 3, i have to insert in a simple list char number 3, which is c. So the problem is that the exercise must be done without using any auxiliar structures, such as an auxiliar list or an auxiliar stack. My doubt is how do I reach number 1 on the stack without losing number 3 and number 5 and without placing them in an auxiliar structure.

In advance, thanks.

Comment: Well, you have to put them somewhere, and the only other structure you can use is the list...

Comment: Why do you need to preserve the values in the stack? If I'm understanding the assignment correctly, once you've used the stack value to index into the list, you're done with it and can forget about it. In other words, repeat `result.append(list.get(stack.pop()))` until the stack is empty. Is that incorrect?

Comment: @jpm yes, one I insert the assigned char in the list, I don't need the value, but the first one to insert must be the char that equals 1, which in this case is c, but i can't afford to lose number 3 and 5, because i need to insert those chars later.

Comment: @trutheality it says its possible to do it without putting them somewhere else... to be honest, that was an exercise from a test, and and i did it using another structure to place them, and the professor told me that it was clearly wrong, and doable without another additional structure.

Comment: I think one of us is misunderstanding the problem. Any chance you could post the actual text?

Comment: @jpm as I posted in a comment, it was an exercise from a test so i can't post the original text. let my try to explain myself: i created another method but instead of using a stack, using a cue, and it was fairly easy, as i could compare a counter to the number, and un-cue the first value and cue it again until the first value was 1 while, at the same time, i moved the head of the circular list to the next character, and then, adding 1 to the counter when the value was found. i'm sorry if it seems hard to understand, but i can't seem to be able to explain it in a better way.

Comment: @Jmdjorgeek What I meant is that you could insert the values (3, 5, 1) from the stack into the circular list and then put them (5, 3) back on the stack.

Comment: @trutheality that might work, but how can i know that in fact, that node containing a string is actually a number? (i'm new to java)

Comment: @Jmdjorgeek you could call `Integer.parseInt(str);` and catch an exception, or if your numbers are all one-digit you can use `str.charAt(0).isDigit()`. Just google the javadoc for these.

Comment: @Jmdjorgeek Rather than checking for numbers though, it would be better to keep a counter of the number of elements you inserted into the list and use that to tell how many elements to put back on the stack.

Answer (score 0):

Write a recursive function and use the stack for your list

Comment: what would it return? and what do you mean by using the stack for my list? transferring the chars to the stack and the integers to the list?

Answer (score 0):

> i have to insert in a simple list char number 3, which is c

May be I misunderstood  your excersize but you can create a list with a specific number of (empty) nodes. You already know how many nodes.
Then e.g. if the first number of the stack is 3 then insert `c` to the third node of the resulting list etc.

Once you are done the list will be sorted since you entered each number to the proper node.

Comment: that would work but only for a specific case, i need it as a generic method.

Comment: But it is generic.You pop the stack.Get the corresponding char from the list and insert it in the node indicated by the popped value.You keep popping the stack (using the popped value as index) and inserting until you are finished

Answer (score 0):

You could use recursion and store them locally in the call stack.

```
List<Character> charList;

func() {
    Stack<Integer> indexList = new Stack<Integer>();
    indexList.addAll(Arrays.asList(2,4,1,5,3));
    charList = new ArrayList<Character>();
    charList.addAll(Arrays.asList('a','d','c','b','e'));

    recurse(indexList,0);

    for(char c : charList) {
        System.out.println(c);
    }
}

private void recurse(Stack<Integer> indexList, int index){
    int indexChar = indexList.pop();
    char retChar = charList.get(indexChar -1);  
    if(!indexList.isEmpty()) {
        recurse(indexList, (index + 1));
    }       
    charList.set(index, retChar);
}
```